# How do I restrict a string to not allow numbers or special characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have textbox called goalName. In goalName I want to disallow special characters and numbers. I am currently trying the following:

```
 var goalNameValidation = /^[_\W\s]*$/;
 if (goalName == "" || goalNameValidation.test(goalName) == true) {
     //Give Error 
     error = true;
 }
```

This only limits special characters, and not numbers.  How would I go about restricting both?

I can use jQuery for this solution if that is helpful, however vanilla JavaScript would suffice.

Comment: Define “special character” and “number”.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably easier (and more intuitive) to write a regex that matches what you WANT to allow.

```
var goalNameValidation = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
if (goalName == "" || goalNameValidation.test(goalName) == false) {
    //Give Error 
    error = true;
}
```

This way, you can look at it, and see more easily what characters are allowed/not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Change the regexp to:

```
var goalNameValidation = /^[^a-z]*$/i;
```